Repeat zone iterations limit

I am trying to generate a recursive tree using geometry nodes. The iterations define the depth of the tree. The node setup is given below. My problem is after 5 iterations the tree stops growing even if the iterations count is increased. I checked preferences for any limits related to this but was not able to find any. Also, the performance is perfectly alright, i.e. blender doesn't slow down or hang after 5 iterations. I can do all interactions but the iteration count has no effect of tree. Could you help.


This has nothing to do with a repeat zone iterations limit, as there is no formal one; it is constrained only by available resources (see my answer: Geometry Nodes: How to Read Last Digit of a Big Integer?)
Your actual problem is related to instancing depth limit, see: Can I change recursive depth limit of instance ownership?

I did not really find out where it got stuck (and it does not really, the instance count increases in the Spreadsheet, it's just that they seem to be in the same location of previous instances), but if you want your tree to grow further, you have to realize the instances after the Join Geometry node:

